Installing python packages on venv from shared directory using requirements.txt
running:
pip install -e f:\folder0\folder1\folder2\folder3\package_name


does work on venv. but trying to install this local package from a requirements.txt yields an error.
I have several packages which have a setup.py such as
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='package_name',
      version='1.0',
      description='Python Distribution Utilities',
    #   packages=['distutils', 'distutils.command'],
)

and are located in a shared directory:
f:\folder0\folder1\folder2\folder3\package_name

i have a python venv in one machine where i installed all necessary packages.
some are normal instalations and some are from a shared directory which were installed with:
pip install -e F:\folder0\folder1\folder2\folder3\package_name


and everything worked just fine.
Its requirements file looks like this after a pip freeze:
...
dash-table==5.0.0
docopt==0.6.2
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
exchange_calendars==4.5.4
Flask==3.0.0
Flask-Login==0.6.3
# Editable install with no version control (package_name==1.2)
-e f:\folder0\folder1\folder2\folder3\package_name
# Editable install with no version control (package_name1==1.3)
-e f:\folder0\folder1\folder2\folder3\package_name1
# Editable install with no version control (package_name2==1.0)
-e f:\folder0\folder1\folder2\folder3\package_name2
greenlet==3.0.3
idna==3.6
...


However when I tried installing from this requirements.txt (pip install -r requirements.txt) in a new venv in a different machine (powershell, venv active) I get the following error:

ERROR: f:folder0folder1folder2folder3package_name is not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with bzr+http, bzr+https, bzr+ssh, bzr+sftp, bzr+ftp, bzr+lp, bzr+file, git+http, git+https, git+ssh, git+git, git+file, hg+file, hg+http, hg+https, hg+ssh, hg+static-http, svn+ssh, svn+http, svn+https, svn+svn, svn+file).


if i try manually adjusting the file paths in the requirements.txt to:
# Editable install with no version control (package_name==1.2)
-e f:\\folder0\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\package_name

it yields:
ERROR: f:folder0\folder1\folder2\folder3\package_name is not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with bzr+http, bzr+https, bzr+ssh, bzr+sftp, bzr+ftp, bzr+lp, bzr+file, git+http, git+https, git+ssh, git+git, git+file, hg+file, hg+http, hg+https, hg+ssh, hg+static-http, svn+ssh, svn+http, svn+https, svn+svn, svn+file).

Any help would be appreciated.

Does something like file:///F|/folder0/etc work? (Not sure of the precise syntax; many years since I had to suffer from Windows.)

it seems that changing the path to (Capital "F"): F:\folder0\folder1\folder2\folder3\package_name makes it work. Is there a way of making pip write paths in a different format for local packages? If not i think the best solution is to make a script to edit string in the requirements folder.

While Windows file systems are case-insensitive, if the F:\ drive is a shared network resource, it's possible that it is configured as case-sensitive.  That being said, it seems incorrect that the requirements.txt can't be used as is without escaping the \.  Maybe it's worth submitting as an issue to the pip GitHub repo?
